# How to hide 'Print' drop-down button based on state in SO

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I'm getting trouble once how to hide 'Print' drop-down button based on the state of SO, tried on field_view_get function and js but no luck. Do we have any ideas for this solution?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of this button ?

Comment: I added the screenshot, pls take a look

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/view-or-hide-one-report-menu-based-on-condition-in-odoo-8-128946#answer-129476). I think this guy have the same requirement as yours.